# Get files number in a dir in R?

Tags: r

in shell ,to make a dir:

```
mkdir  /home/test
```

then ,to create a file named ".test" in the "/home/test"

```
a=list.files(path = "/home/test",include.dirs = FALSE)
a
character(0)
a=list.files(path = "/home/test",include.dirs = TRUE)
a
character(0)
a=list.files(path = "/home/test/",include.dirs = TRUE)
a
character(0)
list.files(path = '/home/test', all.files=TRUE,inclued.dirs=FALSE)
[1] "."     ".."    ".test"
a=list.files(path = '/home/test', all.files=TRUE)
length(a)
[1] 3
```

how can i get `length(a)` = 1 using regular expression parameters `pattern=` in `list.files` to prune `.` and `..`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `all.files=TRUE` to show all file names including hidden files.

```
list.files(path = '/home/test', all.files=TRUE)
```

---

To answer your edit, one way would be to use a negative number with `tail`

```
tail(list.files(path = '/home/test', all.files=TRUE), -2)
```

---

Using only the `pattern` argument:

```
list.files(path='/home/test', all.files=TRUE, pattern="^[^\\.]|\\.[^\\.]")
```

The `pattern` says "anything that starts with something other than a dot or anything that starts with a dot followed by anything other than a dot."

---

Although it breaks your requirement to use the `pattern` argument of `list.files`, I would actually probably wrap `grep` around `list.statements` in this case.

```
grep("^\\.*\\.$", list.files(path='/home/test', all.files=TRUE), 
     invert=TRUE, value=TRUE)
```

The above will find any file names that only contain dots, then return everything else.  `invert=TRUE` means "find the names that do not match", and `value=TRUE` means "return the names instead of their location."